# How can I have my answer (#12846) undeleted?

Tags: discussion, undelete-request

[One](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12846/where-is-imam-mahdi-now-shias-viewpoint/12854#12854) of my answers was deleted due to an alleged plagiarism. I tried to change the answer by adding more information and rewording and flagged it to be undeleted but the flag was declined. How can I have it undeleted?

[Where is Imam Mahdi now? (Shia's viewpoint)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12846/where-is-imam-mahdi-now-shias-viewpoint)

Answer (score 2):

Besides the fact that the edits don't actually address most of the actual plagiarism that the original post was deleted for (compare, for example, http://islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa2018), undeleting posts that *were* plagiarised is not standard practice here. As Shog9 mentioned last time he weighed in on the rampant plagiarism on this site (emphasis mine):

> Allow authors to re-post answers when the new answer corrects the problems identified in the old one. **Refrain from *undeleting* answers that were originally plagiarized** - this just rewards trickery.

Your original post was by all appearances heavily plagiarised; every single action (including votes) taken on it was based entirely on the work of someone else rather than your own. Even if your changes *did* address the plagiarism, such changes would render the new post *so* fundamentally different from the original that every single vote it had already attracted would become wholly irrelevant.

There is no reason to undelete this post. Just post a new answer — one that is actually original content based on your own knowledge and expertise rather than just regurgitated from somewhere else (i.e. plagiarism) — and let the system work as intended.

Comment: What will your answer be if some asks the result of 2+2? Oh, if you say 4, you've plagiarized! I found some else answering this question in a similar manner!